# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/camunda/bpm/engine/variable/VariableMap

Tags: java, maven, junit, camunda

I am trying to test a JavaDelegate and need to Mock the DelegateExecution class from Camunda.
I am using below method to mock the input :

DelegateExecution execution = CamundaMockito.delegateExecutionFake();

but this returns following error stack :

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/camunda/bpm/engine/variable/VariableMap

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.camunda.bpm.engine.variable.VariableMap

I m using maven to build the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class VariableMap is part of the following maven artifact:

```
<groupId>org.camunda.commons</groupId>
<artifactId>camunda-commons-typed-values</artifactId>
```

So if you include that in the correct version in your maven pom, this class should be found.